# Change all data table names in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7 worksheets for a brand. And I have 10 brands
All worksheets contain multiple data tables with a precise name
All table begin with "brand_"

I made a macro to copy all worksheets for all brands (resulting in 70 worksheets) working great.
But when I copy the worksheet, all tables are named as "brand_" + table name + 3 digits number with "brand_" the same brand as the original one.
In my macro, I loop throught all brands so I always know which brand I'm dealing with.
Is there a way to change all table names when I copy the worksheet instead of having to change everything manually?

```
Sub copy()
Dim all_brands As Variant
Dim all_tabs As Variant
Dim brand As Variant
Dim sheettocopy As Variant
Dim OLDsheet As String
Dim NEWsheet As String
all_brands = Array("xxx", "yyy", "jjj", "zzz", "ppp", "qqq", "vvv", "bbb")
all_tabs = Array("tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4", "tab5", "tab6", "tab7")

For Each brand In all_brands
   For Each sheettocopy In all_tabs
       OLDsheet = "MMM" & sheettocopy
       Sheets(OLDsheet).copy after:=Sheets(OLDsheet)
       NEWsheet = brand & sheettocopy
       ActiveSheet.Name = NEWsheet
   Next sheettocopy
Next brand

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, here is my solution:

```
For Each brand In all_brands
    For Each sheettocopy In all_tabs
    OLDsheet = "MMM" & sheettocopy
    Sheets(OLDsheet).copy after:=Sheets(OLDsheet)
    NEWsheet = brand & sheettocopy
    ActiveSheet.name = NEWsheet

        For Each tbl In Worksheets(NEWsheet).ListObjects
        name = tbl.name
        length = Len(name) - 6
        newname = brand & Mid(name, 4, length)
        tbl.name = newname
        Next tbl

Next sheettocopy
Next brand
```